# How to implement preemptive scheduling using HAL in STM32F103RB

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32

I coded programs which uses two buttons and external interrupts to turn on each leds. I wanted to use preemptive scheduling by using priority. but my HAL-used program runs only Tail-Chaining Interrupt mod. Is there a way to implement preemptive scheduling?

```cpp
int main(void) {
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  while (1) {
    if(flag_Sw1 == 1) {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6,  GPIO_PIN_SET);
      flag_Sw1=0;
      HAL_Delay(200);
    } else if (flag_Sw2 == 1) {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      flag_Sw2=0;
      HAL_Delay(200);
    }
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  }
}

.
.
.
// in the MX_GPIO_Init(void)

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);

.
.
.

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_PIN) {
    if(GPIO_PIN == GPIO_PIN_8) {
        flag_Sw1 = 1;
        flag_Sw2 = 0;
    }
    else if(GPIO_PIN == GPIO_PIN_13) {
        flag_Sw1 = 0;
        flag_Sw2 = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need a scheduler, I don't think HAL provides one. Luckily the architecture of the Cortex M makes it trivial to write one.  https://bitbucket.org/csowter/redkernel/src/master/ is an example I wrote for cortex m4, it would be easy to adapt it for cortex m3s.

Comment: Do you really need to write your own scheduler when they already exist - including for free via Mbed OS2, Mbed OS 5, freeRTOS and others?  The CMSIS defines a common RTOS API for Cortex-M devices and is implemented for several underlying RTOS including RTX (used by Mbed)

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried another way and it acts as intended. I really appreciate to your attention!

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing tail chaining rather than preemption, then it's possible that NVIC priority grouping isn't configured as you expect - and thus configuring the two interrupts into priority groups 0 and 1 has no effect on interrupt preemption.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the freeROS which is supported by the STM CUBE. Writing the scheduler is just part of the job. You need the sync mechnisms as well